# IE 8 CSS li's are showing incorrectly

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, html-lists, carousel

I'm using a Carousel in the link below under the section "PROPERTY DOCUMENTS". In IE 8 the li's are looking weird they aren't wide like they look in modern browsers.

Is there a simple fix on this so that it can look good in IE8? Right now I have the following custom attributes on the li's but am having no luck. They aren't showing up at all in IE7 so I'm hoping that this fix will have them show up in IE7 also.

```
   .boutique img{

    }

    .boutique a {

    }

    .boutique li {

    }
```

I just recently took out the css I had. It was making things worse.

Here is the jQuery...

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#boutique').boutique({
    container_width:    200,
    front_img_width:     58,
    front_img_height:    72,
    starter:              3,
    speed:              900,
    hovergrowth:        0.2,
    behind_opacity:     0.3,
    back_opacity:         1,
    frames:               3,
    autoplay:         false,
    hovergrowth:          0,
    freescroll:       false,
    move_on_hover:    false,
    text_front_only:   true,
    });
});
```

and the link to the jQuery file. http://landpros.turnpostinteractive.com/javascripts/jquery.boutique.js

Here is the HTML to the boutique.

```
<div id="parent">
            <img id="prev-boutique" src="images/details-page/prev.png" onclick="boutique_previous()" />
            <img id="next-boutique" src="images/details-page/next.png" onclick="boutique_next()" />
            <!-- The Boutique HTML: -->
            <ul id="boutique">
                <li>
                    <a href="#frame1">
                        <img src="images/details-page/round-about.jpg">
                        <span>Optional description.</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#frame1">
                        <img src="images/details-page/round-about.jpg">
                        <span>Optional description.</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#frame1">
                        <img src="images/details-page/round-about.jpg">
                        <span>Optional description.</span>
                    </a>
                </li>           
            </ul>
        </div>
```

http://landpros.turnpostinteractive.com/LandPros_Details2_1.html

Here is a link to what its doing in ie8... https://i.stack.imgur.com/abVrt.jpg

Any help would be awesome! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I just checked the `<li>` elements of the code.
Looks like the javascript you are using is not IE8optimized. It sets the `width:58px` of the `<li>` elements in all the browsers but sets the width as `6px` in IE8. Can you give a link to your jQuery code that you are using for the images?

**EDIT#1**

Add a property `width:25%` to all the `<li>` elements.
Define a class `.dummy` with property `width:36%` for the following javascript.

Then add this javascript:

```
var liElements = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
for (var i = 0; i < liElements.length; i++) {
  var liElement = liElements[i];
  if (liElement.style.top == "0px" && liElement.style.left == "0px") {
    liElement.className += "dummy"; 
  }
  else{
  liElement.className -= "dummy";
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry that was me, I was messing with an ie8 only stylesheet and put a width of 58px on the li's... Here is the jQuery I'm using. I'll add it above.

Comment: I just updated the original post. Sorry about that. Seemed like something that should be in the main question. @xan

Comment: I don't know the problem that may be causing it. You will have to manually set the `width` using javascript.

Comment: yep, I re-posted the HTML in the original post again.

Comment: @b-lew: Please add the CSS as well for the `boutique` class.

Comment: Try adding `width:36%` to the `.boutique li` element.

Comment: Okay I have done so. That seems to have worked but it looks longer on the 2 li's behind the main one. They all look the same now though. so thats good!

Comment: I added and it seems to work okay. 

    #boutique li.li2, #boutique li.li1{
 width: 25%;
    }

Its not showing up at all in ie7 though. :-/

Comment: That's not working when they go around in a circle either. :-/

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked by adding this in style.css:
 #boutiqueinit .boutique-frame {border: 1px solid #ffffff;} 
Without this in IE8 the li's were shown incorrectly. That line is from demo.css from http://friquemag.net/demos/boutique/index2.html?v=152 example 2